# How to add cohort to a course programmatically?

Tags: moodle

I want to add addcohort to a course programmatically in moodle. I have gone through the documentation but did find away out this there. Is there any function like `chort_add_course() with parameters as course id and chort id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean add a cohort enrol method to a course? Then users in that cohort will be automatically enrolled onto the course.

The code is in /enrol/cohort/edit.php and /enrol/cohort/edit_form.php - but something like this will do it automatically.

```
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/enrol/cohort/locallib.php');

function cohort_add_course($courseid, $cohortid) {
    global $DB;

    if (!enrol_is_enabled('cohort')) {
        // Not enabled.
        return false;
    }

    if ($DB->record_exists('enrol', array('courseid' => $courseid, 'enrol' => 'cohort'))) {
        // The course already has a cohort enrol method.
        return false;
    }

    // Get the cohort enrol plugin
    $enrol = enrol_get_plugin('cohort');

    // Get the course record.
    $course = $DB->get_record('course', array('id' => $courseid));

    // Add a cohort instance to the course.
    $instance = array();
    $instance['name'] = 'custom instance name - can be blank';
    $instance['status'] = ENROL_INSTANCE_ENABLED; // Enable it.
    $instance['customint1'] = $cohortid; // Used to store the cohort id.
    $instance['roleid'] = $enrol->get_config('roleid'); // Default role for cohort enrol which is usually student.
    $instance['customint2'] = 0; // Optional group id.
    $enrol->add_instance($course, $instance);

    // Sync the existing cohort members.
    $trace = new null_progress_trace();
    enrol_cohort_sync($trace, $course->id);
    $trace->finished();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in enrol/cohort/ajax.php and scroll down to "case 'enrolcohort':". There isn't a single cohort enrolment function, but the few lines of code there should cover what you want.

Note - you could also use the 'enrolcohortusers' section just below this - the difference is the first will continue to update enrolments if new users are added to / removed from the cohort, the second adds the current users, but doesn't update in the future.